# Blender Invisible Weight Paint?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

The Mouth keeps moving when I try to move the arm. However I cannot delete the Vertices from weight paint. Nor do they show up in the Vertex Weight List:

[image]

Here is a video of what the problem is and what another version of the character was like (where everything worked properly):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOasFEq_P3g

I hope this is not a blender bug and I am overseeing something trivial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally, you'd click Armature tab >> Display >> Envelope, Tab into Edit mode, N to bring up properties, Right-click on offending bones, reduce their Envelope setting.  However your screen displays Vertex Weights instead.  Are you using a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move the bone 14 (upper arm), probably you are moving the forearm and hand bone also: check if there is some weight relative to theese other bones in your moving vertex.

Check also if the number you see in the vertex weight tab (0.000) is a true null value (maybe is 0.000024 which is not null).

Comment: Of course. Now I feel like an idiot. I actually knew that, but forgot, I didn't rig or animate anything for months